# How can I create one new column in parse table with default value

Tags: database, parse-platform, nosql

I am working on a project which have parse database.

Requirements is to add new column in table with default value. I tried following things but they didn't work.

[createNewColumnStep2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EW2TS.png)
[image: createNewColumnStep1]

Event I tried updating the value of this new column via Cloud console, Iterating all users and tried updating value of it but id doesn't work

Error was

> {"code":206,"message":"Parse::UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError"}

[image: CloudCodeWithBashCommandAndErrorLog]

Answer (score 0):

All your requirement is creating a new column on User class.

In step 2, you success create a column.

After step 2, you should set initial value on BeforeSave _User.

```js
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
    var user = request.object;
    if(user.isNew()){
        user.set('key', value);
    }
    response.success();
});
```

After step 3, all new user will be created with the value.

Step 4, you should init all existed user object with default value.

The way you call this cloud function is without enough permission.
You can save objects with masterKey.

```js
Parse.Object.saveAll(users,{
    userMasterKey:true,
    success: function(){},
    error: funciton(){}
});
```